# How to uninstall app that seems to be an adds?? *The app that I accidentally install is not an apk but in the form of system app and I forgot the name

Tags: malware, samsung-galaxy-j7

This is the picture

It's really nice to have some one helping..
Thanks[image]

Comment: Holding down on the white square at the top left of the advertisement app tab thing as shown in the screenshot *should* take you to the app's info panel, where you'll be able to uninstall the app.

Answer (score 1):

Long Press on the icon for the app in your recent applications list and it'll show you exactly what package caused the ad page.

Ad's aren't usually incorporated in system apps because you've already paid for them and it'd be double charging, Developers add adverts to their apps to help support their creativity, You can't just make apps for free as it's the same as digging a whole without a ladder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `System App` which shows you adds. Adds are added by `Developers` for earning. Check your Device for any `3rd Party App` which shows add even after closing it.

Comment: I disagree. Gmail shows advertisements, though only inside the app but nevertheless it does, and it is a system app!